# Save id in both entities via Hibernate + JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, one-to-one

I have two entities that have a relation OneToOne, like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "FOO")
Foo{
    
    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "foo")
    @Cascade({org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.ALL})
    @JoinColumn(name = "BAR_ID")
    private Bar bar;

    // getters and setters
 }

 @Entity
 @Configurable
 @Table(name = "BAR")
 Bar{
    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "FOO_ID")
    @Cascade({org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.ALL})
    private Foo foo;

    // getters and setters
 }
```

In the Service layer, I make the connection by setting Bar in Foo:

```
 Bar.setFoo(foo);
 barDAO.saveOrUpdate(bar);
```

Which saves the foo id in the Bar table. But the opposite doesn't happen. Is it possible for hibernate to save both ids making only one set? I thought this would be working already

Comment: _"The opposite doesn't happen"_ what does that mean? There is one FK present in the DB ... in Bar. There will NEVER be a FK in the Foo table!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to understand the relationships well first. As much I see here you might trying to have a bidirectional **OneToOne** relationship between `Foo` and `Bar`.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "FOO")
Foo {

     @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
     @JoinColumn(name = "BAR_ID")
     private Bar bar;

     // getters and setters
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "BAR")
Bar{

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "bar")
    private Foo foo;

    // getters and setters
}
```

> In the bidirectional association two sides of association exits –
>   owning and inverse. For one to one bidirectional relationships, the
>   owning side corresponds to the side that contains the appropriate
>   foreign key.

Here the **owning side** is the `Foo` and BAR_ID would be that foreign key. Having join column in both end doesn't make sense. And Relation will be cascaded from the `Foo` to `Bar`. And the **inverse side** is `Bar` here that needs to be annotated with `mapped by` value of the owning side reference.

Now if you set `Bar` object in `Foo` it will persist the `Bar` object along with the mapping with `Foo`. Doing the reverse thing doesn't make sense. isn't it ?

Comment: But Hibernate will get Bar from Foo if I just call foo.getBar()? Or do I have to explicitly add it on the DAO layer (change the getById method)?

Comment: yes, Hibernate will do that for you. All associated field except the `LAZY` ones will be fetched in your object and `foo.getbar()` will return associated `Bar`

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the opposite side of the relation.

If you say `bar.setFoo(foo)` then after you have to say `foo.setBar(bar)` or of course you can do this within the `setFoo` method as well.

Cascading means that it will trigger the operation on the relation, however in your case, the relation was unfinished as one side was missing.